# How do I de-reference a pointer that is inside of an array using its index?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dereference

I am working on a stacks assignment in which we are creating a stack of pointers to structs called Data. Our professor is trying to help us develop good habits in regards to security in designing a program, which is why we have a stack of pointers to structs rather than a stack of the structs themselves.

I know that typically when de-referencing a pointer, you do it with an asterisk. Example:

```
int x = 5;
int* xptr = &x;
cout << *xptr << endl;
```

My understanding is that the above code would create a var x with the value 5, then a pointer that store the address of the var x, and then by printing *xptr, you are de-referencing the pointer, which causes the printed output to be the value of x (5). If I'm incorrect anywhere so far, let me know.

So now onto the stack class, my professor created the .h file for us and we have these attributes:

```
int top; // this is your top index
Data *stack[STACK_SIZE];
```

My understanding of the stack is that we have an array of pointers to Data structs (as indicated by the * prior to the name "stack") and the stack is literally named "stack". My question is: when I need to pop a Data struct off (I'm calling it popData) and I want to assign its value, I know that I can't just do popValue = stack[top] because popValue is of type Data, which can't receive an assignment of a pointer.

I was thinking I could do this:

```
Data popData;
*Data popDataPtr;
popDataPtr = stack[top];
popData = *popPtr;
```

I am thinking that logically this would work, but I was wondering if there is syntax for de-referencing the ptr and assigning it in the same line. I'm thinking either:

```
popData = *stack[top];
```

or

```
popData = stack[*top];
```

But I'm not sure what's correct. I can't seem to find an example online of this. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: I think `*stack[top]` should compile. If it does not, `*(stack[top])` certainly will (I don't remember the precedence off the top).

Comment: Did you try compiling and running the 2 versions to see what happens?

Comment: _Our professor is trying to help us develop good habits in regards to security in designing a program, which is why we have a stack of pointers to structs rather than a stack of the structs themselves._ Did your professor justify that statement?

Comment: You should just try all the code examples yourself, as @cigien suggested.

Comment: Arrays of pointers (and pointers to arrays) were never my strong suite so I'm not 100% sure what the right thing is here, but I'm fairly sure that `*top` is not right. `top` is not a pointer, so you shouldn't have to deference it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend trying it next time by yourself to see which of your examples would work.

You can have the assignment in one line, and I would recommend also adding parentheses in complex expressions like this, so you don't have to memorize operator precedence:

```
Data popData = *(stack[top]);
```

---

Small comment regarding your other code, this will not compile:

```
*Data popDataPtr;
```

The syntax for a pointer to a `Data` is no different from a pointer to an `int`, which you had before:

```
int* xptr = &x;
```

So to make the code from your example work, you actually need

```
Data* popDataPtr;
```

There is a great rule of thumb in C++: read the declarations **from right to left**, for example:

```
Data * const ptr1; // ptr1 is a constant pointer to a Data
const Data * ptr2; // ptr2 is a pointer to Data which is const (or just to a constant Data)
Data * arr1[]; // arr1 is an array of pointers to Data.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
popData = *stack[top]; // this will do the trick
```

Here you are accessing the pointer that you want and you are then dereferencing that pointer and storing the data pointed to in `popData`

Comment: Except that here, `stack` is an array of pointers. `[]` gives you a single pointer, that the OP wants to further dereference.